Why is the connection still open?
I got this error when navigating some of my C# app

The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

It happens in these methods:
public DataTable getTable(string query)
{
    cn.ConnectionString = myConnection();
    cm = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);

    return table;
}

public void ExecuteQuery(String sql)
{
    try
    {
        cn.ConnectionString = myConnection();
        cn.Open();

        cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public String getPassword(string username)
{
    string password = "";
    cn.ConnectionString = myConnection();
    cn.Open();
    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT password FROM tbUser WHERE username = '"+ username + "'", cn);
    dr= cm.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    if(dr.HasRows)
    {
        password = dr["password"].ToString();
    }

    dr.Close();
    cn.Close();

    return password;
}

public double ExtractData(string sql)
{
    cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = myConnection();

    cn.Open();

    cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

    double data = double.Parse(cm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    cn.Close();

    return data;
}

I have no idea why I get this error. How can I fix it?

Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

What is the actual problem here? The only thing you've did is dumping a wall of code. What exactly isn't working? What exact piece of code is throwing an error? Please have a look at [ask].

Mistake #1: caching the connection object. Never do this. Just create a new connection in a using block, runn commands and dispose. Also: parameterize your queries, do not inject data into your SQL. And don't store plain-text passwords, salt-and-hash them instead.

This happens because you're keeping a single connection object for use throughout the entire app. Don't do that!
ADO.Net (the built-in database libraries provided by .Net) use a feature called connection pooling, where the connection type you see and use in your code is just a lightweight wrapper with a reference to a much "heavier" object managed by a pool. When you keep the same connection, you optimize the small thing (the wrapper) at the expense of the big thing (the real connection in the pool), making the app slower, use more memory (not less), and prone to connection bottlenecks. It can also cause issues exactly like what you're seeing in this question.
You should allocate a brand new connection object for most queries. Really.
Make sure the connection is short-lived and disposed properly as quickly as possible. The best way to do this is with a using block or using statement.

Separately, never Never NEVER use string concatenation like that to include data in an SQL statement. What if I entered the following as my username? :

';DROP TABLE tbUser; --

(Hint: don't try that if you value your tbUser table)
This is just one of many ways to exploit SQL when string concatenation is involved. The correct alternative is using query parameters, such that user input is never substituted directly into the SQL, even by the server.
This means the getTable(), ExtractData(), and ExecuteQuery() methods are all fundamentally flawed and need to be removed (or extended), because as-written they force you to build SQL in a crazy-vulnerable way.

Finally, it's not okay to store passwords in plain-text... not even for practice/learning/proof of concept projects. Look on NuGet for the BCrypt library and learn how to use it.
Therefore the myConnection() method should create and return a new connection object, and you would call it like this:
private SqlConnection myConnection()
{
   return new SqlConnection(" connection string here ");
}

public bool Login(string username, string attemptedPassword)
{
    var SQL = "SELECT PasswordHash FROM tbUser WHERE Username = @Username";
    using var cn = myConnection();
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn);
    // use the actual column and type and length here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbtype.NVarChar, 25).Value = username;

    cn.Open();
    var hash = (string)cmd.ExecuteNonquery();

    return !string.IsNullOrEmpyt(hash) && BCrypt.Verify(attemptedPassword, hash);
}

Even better if you modify the above to return a user object instead of a boolean.

Good answer. PBKDF2 is supported in .NET, no need for another library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.pbkdf2?view=net-8.0
